# Examples of user-writeable config files?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration-files, dsl

Looming on my (C# 4.0) project horizon is the introduction of a user-configuration feature, wherein my colleagues need to obtain the ability to configure our software or a pre-run basis so that it will perform its duties in whatever way is needed. Every run (they'll tend to be lengthy simulations) will have have its own configuration file.

In the main, they'll want to define "products", fairly complex beasts comprising run-time parameters, IOC-style information (lists of calculation classes required in a [Strategy Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StrategyPattern)-like way) and more stuff besides. Values could be numbers (integer and floating-point), strings, dates and lists of these.

We know the content will change (new parameter names, for example) as new products are introduced or existing ones evolve.

Options I've looked at include, in descending order of (my estimate of) syntax-heaviness:

1. [XML](http://www.xml.com/)
2. [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/)
3. [JSON](http://www.json.org/)
4. a [DomainSpecific Language](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DomainSpecificLanguage.html)?
5. Some app-specific text notation

I'm looking for examples of more-or-less similar things: file formats, discussions of pros and cons from a technical and/or user perspective.

(I expect that at some time in the future we'll consider introducing a graphic front-end for such exercises, but we'll need to be able to configure executions some time before then.)

EDIT/UPDATE: I'm *not* particularly concerned about ease of implementation from the technical perspective: I'm looking for something my (very smart, but not technically-oriented) *users* will best be able to use to minimize the difficulty of writing what may be a fairly complex configuration.

Maybe "configuration" is a bad choice of word - what if we called it "simulation definition file" and considered that each user will create many of these over time?

Comment: Another option to consider would be a small file-based database, such as SQLite or MS SQL Compact Edition.

Answer (score 0):

If all of this can be described in a regular, attribute oriented way, it sounds like XML would meet your needs.  C# has fantastic XML handling features including built-in serializers and LINQ that can save a ton of code implementation time.  Also, creating a forms based UI from a schema  is very straight forward.

I would suggest sitting down and creating a pseudo-schema to see if this would handle your use cases to help decide if this approach would work for you.

For examples, take a look at one of the many plugin systems that are driven by XML.  The first one I would recommend is Eclipse.

Comment: Is this the best option for my users? They have to write many config files, I only have to process them.

Comment: Possibly.  It all depends on the interface.  As I mentioned, creating forms from an XML schema is fairly easy and there are great tools for this.  Check out Eclipse forms or the PDE editor for some great examples.

Answer (score 0):

In C# easiest way is to use a Built In Class `System.Configuration` ,first you should add an Configuration File ,using Visual Studio ,than you can edit it's attributes . Here is a [How To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx)

Comment: You can create custom sections, and these can be writeable, including writing overrides of the `app.config` to per-user files (and this avoids permission problems – users can write to their config whereas they shouldn't be able to write to the global configuration).